# Accessing a Javascript class's method from outside its scope

Tags: javascript, class, module, scope, webpack-4

I'm bundling a JS class, using webpack-4, but I cannot access any of the methods and properties of it from outside its scope. I followed some of the suggestions given here but I'm still stuck. Below you'll see a simplified version of what I need to achieve. Any suggestions on how to get this to work would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

`My webpack.config:`

```
output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../assets/js'), 
        library: 'MyModule',
        libraryTarget: 'var',
    },
```

`The class file, Main.js:`

```
export  class  Main{
  prop1 = 'This is Main.prop1';

  static hello = ()=>{
    console.log('Hello from Main');
  }

  static hi = function(){
    console.log('Hi from Main');
  }
}
```

`Inside test.html:`

```
<script src="./Main.js"></script>
<script>
window.onload = function(){
        var mainUX = MyModule;
        console.log(mainUX); // see output below**
        console.log(mainUX.prop1) // outputs 'undefined'
        mainUX.hello(); // Outputs Uncaught TypeError: mainUX.hello is not a function
        mainUX.hi();
       };
</script>
```

`** In the console I get:`

```
Object { Main: Getter, … }
​Main: 
​__esModule: true
​Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"
​<get Main()>: function js()​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​​__defineGetter__: function __defineGetter__()
​​__defineSetter__: function __defineSetter__()
​​__lookupGetter__: function __lookupGetter__()
​​__lookupSetter__: function __lookupSetter__()
​​__proto__: 
​​constructor: function Object()
​​hasOwnProperty: function hasOwnProperty()
​​isPrototypeOf: function isPrototypeOf()
​​propertyIsEnumerable: function propertyIsEnumerable()
​​toLocaleString: function toLocaleString()
​​toString: function toString()
​​valueOf: function valueOf()
​​​length: 0
​​​name: "valueOf"
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `<script src="./Main.js"></script>` you should just use `import Main from './main.js'` in your last script tag

Comment: thanks for the feedback. But If I do that I get this `Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module` ... which makes sense, the script inside my page is not a module itself. Am I missing something?

Comment: Omg so sorry i forgot, change your script tag to `<script type="module"> ... </script>`

Comment: thank you so much... but that didn't work either ;(, I found an answer online, just by luckily stumbing into an article, that solved my problem. I'll add it the solution and the link to the resource below so that it can help some other folks.

Answer (score 0):

After a whole day trying to find an answer to my issue, I came across this [article](https://dev.to/riversun/recipes-on-how-to-create-a-library-that-supports-both-browser-and-node-js-201m). It is very thorough, easily to follow, and my issue got solved right away. Below I am attaching the code with the corrections in case someone finds it useful.

I had to change the `webpack.config` file, and add `default` to the class export.

`webpack.config:`

```
output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../assets/js'), 
        library: '',
        libraryExport: '',
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
        globalObject: 'this',
    },
```

`The class file, Main.js:`

```
export default class Main{

  prop1 = 'This is Main.prop1';

  hello = ()=>{
    console.log('Hello from inside MainUX');
  }

  hi = function(){
    console.log('Hi from Main');
  }
}
```

`Inside test.html:`

```
// in the head:
<script src="./Main.js"></script>

// elsewhere in the html document
<script>
    const Main = window.default;
    const mainUX = new Main();
    console.log(Main)
    mainUX.hi();
</script>
```